# How to make labels, captions and field headers Content Manageable in ASP.Net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

I have a development requirement where i need to make everything content manageable in an ASP.Net 3.5 application. We are not following MVC model, although we have our app based on 3 tiers. Also we are not using any opensource framework like DNN for instance.

I like to know how can we specifically make ***Field Labels***, ***Form Captions*** and ***Field Headers*** content mangeable without using any framework?

I would welcome all technical and innvotive ideas on this question. Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify `Form Caption` and `Field Header` terms?

Comment: @Yuriy Rozhovetskiy Sure! By Form Caption, i meant the caption text property of the form. And by Field Header, i meant the column header text property of the data grid. If you have worked in Visual Studio, you would know what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Resource Files and using the `meta:resourcekey` attribute on your controls?

```
<asp:Label Runat="server" meta:resourcekey="MyLabel" />
```

and in the resource file

```
MyLabel.Text = "My Label Text"
```

Additionally, if you want to store the information in some other medium, you can create a Custom Resource Provider ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx )